A question about the unique support plane of convex functions
I met the question when reading the section 2.1 of the book of Lieb and Loss, "Analysis".
Let $\Omega$ be a convex open set in $\mathbb{R}^n $. Given a convex function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x$ is a point in $\Omega$. A support plane to the graph of $f$ at  $x$ is defined as a plane that touches the graph $(x, f(x))$ at $x$ and that nowhere lies above the graph. Namely, there exists an vector $V\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for any $y\in \Omega$,
$$f(y)\geqslant f(x)+V\cdot(y-x).$$
If the support plane is unique, than it is called a tagent plane.
But sadly I do not know how to prove the following claim for $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n \geqslant 2$.
If $f$ is convex, the existence of a tangent plane at $x$ is equivalent to differentiability at $x$.
If $n=1$, using the fact that the left and right derivative exists at any point $x$, it is easy to find different support planes when $f^{\prime}_{-}(x)\neq f^{\prime}_{+}(x)$. Also, when $f$ is differentiable at $x$, it is easy to find $y$ that does not satisfy the inequality for other $V$ at $x$.
But for higher dimension, I just donot know what to do. Please help me find the proof.

What do you mean by equivalent? It is not an “if and only if” statement. In other words, you can have a convex function with a tangent plane at $x$, but the function is not differentiable at $x$. $f(x) = |x|$, for example.

@msantama Here tagent plane means the unique support plane. For $f(x)=\vert x \vert$ at $x=0$, there are many different support planes.
